# Extra } or forgotten $

Tags: errors, algorithm2e

I get several errors on this algorithm. Errors like "Missing } inserted" and "Extra } or forgotten $". Anyone can tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
{\SetAlgoNoLine
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
  \If{notificheAttivate {\bf and} today \leq dataScadenza}{
    \If{today \geq dataInizioPreavviso}{
        \If{notificaTS == null {\bf or} (notificaTS == null {\bf and} frequenza == daily)}{sendNotification()}}
  }
\caption{Algoritmo di notifica con frequenza giornaliera}
\end{algorithm}}
```

Comment: You need `$\leq$` and `$\geq$`. Note that `\bf` has been deprecated for more than 20 years. Use `\textbf{and}`.

Comment: Also do not use `[h!]` usually it just generates a warning that latex has to change it, better to use `[htp]` unless you have good reason to prevent the float appearing at top  of page or on a float page (restricting it in that way makes it likely to go to the end of the document)

Comment: Is this question still open ?